# validation a xml with several xsd schema DOM java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xsd-validation

After search on internet and in differnets forums, have not found my answer.
 
I have a XML file which is define by two XSD schema. 
 
For write the XML file, there are two ways to write the XML file :
 
(I have to delete the "<" charactere to display the XML file)
 
First methode to write it :

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
Policy xmlns="http://www.W3C.com/Policy/v3#"  xmlns:ns2="http://www.W3C.com   /PolicyExtension/v3#">
DigestAlg Algorithm="http://test"/>
Transforms>
Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n20010315"></Transform>
/Transforms>
     ns2:Validation>
         ns2:ConditionID>1.0.1</ns2:ConditionID>
         ns2:TConditionID>1.0.2</ns2:TConditionID>
      /ns2:Validation>
/Policy>"
```

second methodes :

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
Policy xmlns="http://www.W3C.com/Policy/v3#">
DigestAlg Algorithm="http://test"/>
Transforms>
Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n20010315"></Transform>
/Transforms>
     Validation xmlns:ns2="http://www.W3C.com/PolicyExtension/v3#">
         ConditionID>1.0.1</ns2:ConditionID>
         TConditionID>1.0.2</ns2:TConditionID>
      /Validation>
/Policy>
```

For pasring my XML files, i use :

```
InputStream doc = new FileInputStream(myXMLFile);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    SchemaFactory sf =     SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    List<Source> sourceListSchema = new ArrayList<Source>();
    sourceListSchema.add(new StreamSource(SignaturePolicy.class.getResourceAsStream(MY_XSD_SCHEMA_1)));
    sourceListSchema.add(new StreamSource(SignaturePolicy.class.getResourceAsStream(MY_XSD_SCHEMA_2)));

    Schema schema;
    try {
        Source[] sourceTmp = new Source[1];
        schema = sf.newSchema(sourceListSchema.toArray(sourceTmp));
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        LogMachine.logger.severe(
                "SAXException : The schema can not be parse :"+e.getMessage());
    }

    dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    dbf.setIgnoringComments(true);
    dbf.setSchema(schema);

    DocumentBuilder db;
    try {
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        documentPolicy = db.parse(Doc); 
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        LogMachine.logger.severe(
                "ParserConfigurationException : the file can not be parse by DOM :"+e.getMessage());
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        LogMachine.logger.severe(
                "SAXException : the file can not be parse by DOM :"+e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LogMachine.logger.severe(
                "IOException : the file can not be open like a file :"+e.getMessage());
    }
```

When I want to parse this documents with DOM, the first XML file display an error

Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.ls.LSException: The prefix "ns2" for element "ns2:Validation" is not bound.

But the second XML file is well parse.

Someone can help me to parse the two documents ??
Thank you for you help

Comment: You cannot use an XML namespace if you did not define it. Why couldn't you use the second XML document?